# AVaudioplayer not loading an existing and playable file swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I run into a problem creating a module that records voice and plays the result. The problem is that if a record  and play it works but if a record and later I get the file created before and try to play I get the: `Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1685348671 "(null)"`
`103:  OpenFromDataSource failed`
`78:  Open failed`

here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
var soundRecorder : AVAudioRecorder!
var SoundPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
var recordingSession: AVAudioSession!

func getFileURL() -> URL {
    let record = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    return record
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupRecorder()
    displaylinkRecording()
}

func setupRecorder(){

    let recordSettings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue
    ]

    do {

        try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        soundRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: getFileURL(), settings: recordSettings)
        soundRecorder.delegate = self
        soundRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
        soundRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    } catch {
        print("error recording")
    }

}
```

I'm updating the file name from a different ViewController:

```
func UpdateNameFile() {
    fileName = reg.idEvent + ".m4a"
    setupRecorder()
}
```

And the corresponding `record` and `play` functions:

```
@IBAction func Recording(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    soundRecorder.record()
    displaylinkRecording()
}

@IBAction func PlayButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    preparePlayer()
    SoundPlayer.play()
    displaylinkPlaying()
}

func preparePlayer(){

    do {
        try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)

        SoundPlayer = try AudioPlayer(contentsOf: getFileURL() as URL)

        SoundPlayer.delegate = self
        SoundPlayer.isMeteringEnabled = true
        SoundPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        SoundPlayer.volume = 1.0
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

so in other words, if I try to record and play, works, but if I try to play getting a file that I know is in the directory and was created before, doesn't work. And I cannot see why...

Any advice?

Comment: Show the code where you save the file to the documents directory.

Comment: is in the first block of code `func getFileURL() -> URL` and then used here: `soundRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: getFileURL(), settings: recordSettings)`

Comment: I'm seeing this exact same error code, but it only seems to happen in the Simulator. You get the same behavior on a device?